# how to customize mat paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat, paginator

in my project i need to iterate through an array and display a single item at a time. The array navigation should be through a Next and a Previous button. I used mat table to achieve this along with mat paginator.

Is there any way to customize the mat paginator such that I get text labels as Next and Previous and the buttons are spaced wide apart ?

How to change the look and feel of the mat paginator?